# Is there a CryptocurrencyData alternative to FinancialData?

Tags: import, web-access, finance, real-time

What's the easiest way to ingest time series data on cryptocurrencies into Mathematica?

I'm looking for up-to-date price, volume, and other properties for both major coins and altcoins.

Comment: I don't believe there's any functionality on crypto in WL directly related to _trading_ crypto, although there is a lot of blockchain stuff in there (like `BlockchainData`). You can use `CurrencyConvert` for a couple of the popular coins as well. You are likely to need to build this functionality yourself from some available API.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple crypto-currencies data sources, but a small proportion of them give a convenient way of extracting crypto-currencies data automatically. I found the easiest to work with to be https://finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies, [YF1].

(I also looked into using  https://data.bitcoinity.org  and https://www.coindesk.com/coindesk20. )

**Remark:** The code below is made with certain ad-hoc inductive reasoning that brought meaningful results. This means the code has to be changed if the underlying data organization in [YF1] is changed.

---

#### Getting cryptocurrencies symbols and summaries

In this section we get all crypto-currencies symbols and related metadata.

Get the data of all crypto-currencies in [YF1]:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  lsData = Import["https://finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies", "Data"]; 
 ]

(*{6.36272, Null}*)
```

Locate the data:

```
pos = First@Position[lsData, {"Symbol", "Name", "Price (Intraday)", "Change", "% Change", ___}];
dsCryptoCurrenciesColumnNames = lsData[[Sequence @@ pos]]
Length[dsCryptoCurrenciesColumnNames]

(*{"Symbol", "Name", "Price (Intraday)", "Change", "% Change", "Market Cap", "Volume in Currency (Since 0:00 UTC)", "Volume in Currency (24Hr)", "Total Volume All Currencies (24Hr)", "Circulating Supply", "52 Week Range", "1 Day Chart"}*)

(*12*)
```

Get the data:

```
dsCryptoCurrencies = lsData[[Sequence @@ Append[Most[pos], 2]]];
Dimensions[dsCryptoCurrencies]

(*{25, 10}*)
```

Make a dataset:

```
dsCryptoCurrencies = Dataset[dsCryptoCurrencies][All, AssociationThread[dsCryptoCurrenciesColumnNames[[1 ;; -3]], #] &]
```

[image]

---

#### Get all time series

In this section we get all the crypto-currencies time series from [YF1].

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ccNow = Round@AbsoluteTime[Date[]] - 
   AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}];
 aCryptoCurrenciesDataRaw =
  Association@
   Map[
    # -> ResourceFunction["ImportCSVToDataset"][
       "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" <> # <>
         "?period1=1410825600&period2=" <> ToString[ccNow] <> 
        "&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"] &, 
    Normal[dsCryptoCurrencies[All, "Symbol"]]
    ];
 ]

(*{6.21141, Null}*)
```

Check we got the data with dimensions retrieval:

```
Dimensions /@ aCryptoCurrenciesDataRaw

(*<|"BTC-USD" -> {2464, 7}, "ETH-USD" -> {2140, 7}, "USDT-USD" -> {2303, 7}, "BNB-USD" -> {1422, 7}, "ADA-USD" -> {1354, 7}, "DOGE-USD" -> {2464, 7}, "XRP-USD" -> {2464, 7}, "USDC-USD" -> {982, 7}, "DOT1-USD" -> {300, 7}, "HEX-USD" -> {547, 7}, "UNI3-USD" -> {77, 7},"BCH-USD" -> {1424, 7}, "LTC-USD" -> {2464, 7}, "SOL1-USD" -> {432, 7}, "LINK-USD" -> {1365, 7}, "MATIC-USD" -> {780, 7}, "THETA-USD" -> {1246, 7}, "XLM-USD" -> {2464, 7}, "ICP1-USD" -> {28, 7}, "VET-USD" -> {1048, 7}, "ETC-USD" -> {1788, 7}, "FIL-USD" -> {1281, 7}, "AMP1-USD" -> {76, 7}, "TRX-USD" -> {1372, 7}, "XMR-USD" -> {2464, 7}|>*)
```

Check we got the data with random sample:

```
RandomSample[#, 6] & /@ KeyTake[aCryptoCurrenciesDataRaw, RandomChoice[Keys@aCryptoCurrenciesDataRaw]]
```

[image]

Here we add the crypto-currencies symbols and convert date strings into date objects.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  aCryptoCurrenciesData = Association@KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, k -> v[All, Join[<|"Symbol" -> k, "DateObject" -> DateObject[#Date]|>, #] &]], aCryptoCurrenciesDataRaw]; 
 ]

(*{8.58146, Null}*)
```

---

#### Summary

In this section we compute the summary over **all** datasets:

```
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][Join @@ Values[aCryptoCurrenciesData], "MaxTallies" -> 30]
```

[image]

---

#### Plots

Here we plot the “Low” and “High” price time series for each crypto-currency for the last 120 days:

```
nDays = 120;
Map[
  Block[{dsTemp = #[Select[AbsoluteTime[#DateObject] > AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Now, -Quantity[nDays, "Days"]]] &]]}, 
    DateListPlot[{
      Normal[dsTemp[All, {"DateObject", "Low"}][Values]], 
      Normal[dsTemp[All, {"DateObject", "High"}][Values]]}, 
     PlotLegends -> {"Low", "High"}, 
     PlotRange -> All] 
   ] &, 
  aCryptoCurrenciesData 
 ]
```

[image]

Here we plot the volume time series for each crypto-currency for the last 120 days:

```
nDays = 120;
Map[
  Block[{dsTemp = #[Select[AbsoluteTime[#DateObject] > AbsoluteTime[DatePlus[Now, -Quantity[nDays, "Days"]]] &]]}, 
    DateListPlot[{
      Normal[dsTemp[All, {"DateObject", "Volume"}][Values]]}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Volume", 
     PlotRange -> All] 
   ] &, 
  aCryptoCurrenciesData 
 ]
```

[image]

---

#### References

[YF1] Yahoo! Finance, [Cryptocurrencies](https://finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies).

Comment: The corresponding notebook can be obtained here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2293868 .

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a CryptocurrencyData alternative to FinancialData?

I implemented a resource function that can be used to obtain cryptocurrency data using the approach explained in [my previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249727/34008).
See
[`CryptocurrencyData`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/antononcube/DeployedResources/Function/CryptocurrencyData):

[image]

---

BTW, `FinancialData` is aware of 10 cryptocurrencies, but that is not documented (as far as I can tell) and only prices are provided. (For more details see the discussion in [`CryptocurrencyData`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/antononcube/DeployedResources/Function/CryptocurrencyData).)

Try

```
DateListPlot@FinancialData["BTC", "Jan 1 2021"]
DateListPlot@FinancialData["ETH", "Jan 1 2021"]
```

[image]